# How to get all items in Elasticsearch for a specific value

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking to sync an Elasticsearch index to another data source. To get the database data I can do:

```
select _id, md5 FROM history
```

What would be the fastest way to do this in ES? I've tried using the scroll API, but it seems deathly slow, having a 10k limit:

```
es.search(index='history', _source=['_id', 'md5'], size=10000))
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll API can be used in parallel fashion via using [slices](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/search-request-scroll.html#sliced-scroll). Theoretically it will allow to have speed up N times with N slices.

The slowness of scroll is due to the fact that Elasticsearch needs to perform a [full scan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_table_scan).

For syncing of Elasticsearch and other DBs I would recommend to have some document queue before Elasticsearch that would send documents to Elasticsearch and to other components. An example of such document queue would be [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/). There is no mechanism (as of my knowledge) that would allow sending new document updates from Elasticsearch to a third party component.

Hope that helps!